# Binding a window button to form validation

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to use the formBind: true on a button to enable/disable it on a modal window according to the validation state of the form.

I want the user to have to confirm the accreditation number, and that validation is working reasonably. However I can't bind the button to the state of validation. I've tried wiring up some event handlers on the text fields to manually handle this, but no event handlers fire.

See this fiddle for the running code:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jrj

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.util.dialogs.Accreditation', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    title: '',
    config: {
        name: ''
    },
    modal: true,


    initComponent:function() {
        var me = this;


        this.title = this.name + ' Accreditation';

        var accreditation1 = new Ext.form.TextField( {
            fieldLabel: 'Accreditation',
            growMin: 250,
            allowBlank: false
        });

       // doesn't fire
       // accreditation1.addListener('activate', function(dis , eOpt) {Ext.Msg.alert("woopy twang");}, this);


        var accreditation2 = new Ext.form.TextField( {
            fieldLabel: 'Confirm',
            growMin: 250,
            allowBlank: false,
            validator: function(value){
                if (accreditation1.getValue() != value){
                    return 'Accreditation numbers must match.'
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        var button1 = new Ext.button.Button({
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'OK',
            itemId: 'btnOK',
        formBind: true

        });


        var button2 = new Ext.button.Button({
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Cancel',
            itemId: 'btnCancel',
            handler: function() {
                this.up('window').close();
            }
        });

        this.items = [
            {
                html: '<h5>Enter your Accreditation Number for ' + this.name + '</h5>'
            },
            accreditation1,
            accreditation2
        ]

           this.buttons = [
                  button1,button2
        ]



        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    handlers: {
        activate : function(dis, opts) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('activate');
            }
    }


});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a formpanel. [From the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-formBind):

> When inside FormPanel, any component configured with `formBind: true` will be enabled/disabled depending on the validity state of the form.

Your example does not contain a form panel. If you put a formpanel into the window, and put the buttons into the form, not into the window, it works:

```
    this.layout='fit';
    this.items = [{
        xtype:'form',
        items:[
            {
                html: '<h5>Enter your Accreditation Number for ' + this.lenderName + '</h5>'
            },
            accreditation1,
            accreditation2
        ],
        buttons: [
            button1,button2
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: I changed to use the form panel and moved my buttons inside the form and now works great. Thank you!